# Python rfecv select less than recommended features

Tags: python, feature-selection, rfe

I have this example code that comes from [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_rfe_with_cross_validation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-feature-selection-plot-rfe-with-cross-validation-py). Optimal number of features recommended by [rfecv](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html) is 3. But if want to build the model with only 1 or 2 features, how should I select those features?

```
"""
===================================================
Recursive feature elimination with cross-validation
===================================================

A Recursive Feature Elimination (RFE) example with automatic tuning of the
number of features selected with cross-validation.

"""

# %%
# Data generation
# ---------------
#
# We build a classification task using 3 informative features. The introduction
# of 2 additional redundant (i.e. correlated) features has the effect that the
# selected features vary depending on the cross-validation fold. The remaining
# features are non-informative as they are drawn at random.

from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(
    n_samples=500,
    n_features=15,
    n_informative=3,
    n_redundant=2,
    n_repeated=0,
    n_classes=8,
    n_clusters_per_class=1,
    class_sep=0.8,
    random_state=0,
)

# %%
# Model training and selection
# ----------------------------
#
# We create the RFE object and compute the cross-validated scores. The scoring
# strategy "accuracy" optimizes the proportion of correctly classified samples.

from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

min_features_to_select = 1  # Minimum number of features to consider
clf = LogisticRegression()
cv = StratifiedKFold(5)

rfecv = RFECV(
    estimator=clf,
    step=1,
    cv=cv,
    scoring="accuracy",
    min_features_to_select=min_features_to_select,
    n_jobs=2,
)
rfecv.fit(X, y)

print(f"Optimal number of features: {rfecv.n_features_}")

# %%
# In the present case, the model with 3 features (which corresponds to the true
# generative model) is found to be the most optimal.
#
# Plot number of features VS. cross-validation scores
# ---------------------------------------------------

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_scores = len(rfecv.cv_results_["mean_test_score"])
plt.figure()
plt.xlabel("Number of features selected")
plt.ylabel("Mean test accuracy")
plt.errorbar(
    range(min_features_to_select, n_scores + min_features_to_select),
    rfecv.cv_results_["mean_test_score"],
    yerr=rfecv.cv_results_["std_test_score"],
)
plt.title("Recursive Feature Elimination \nwith correlated features")
plt.show()

# %%
# From the plot above one can further notice a plateau of equivalent scores
# (similar mean value and overlapping errorbars) for 3 to 5 selected features.
# This is the result of introducing correlated features. Indeed, the optimal
# model selected by the RFE can lie within this range, depending on the
# cross-validation technique. The test accuracy decreases above 5 selected
# features, this is, keeping non-informative features leads to over-fitting and
# is therefore detrimental for the statistical performance of the models.
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your question, RFECV will always return `min_features_to_select` features. If you want 1-2 features, then just pass in 1 or 2 when you create the RFECV object.

For the feature selection among correlated variables, that's a lot harder to do and will involve some level of subjectivity. Here are a few ways I've seen it done:

- Drawing the correlation matrix, identifying features that are correlated with one-another, and selecting whichever one correlates best with your targets (and dropping the others)
- Writing a program to do the above in an iterative fashion, repeatedly throwing away features that are correlated with other features until all the correlations between your features are below some threshold
- RFE, like you're doing
- Taking PCA or PLS is a great way to compress your correlated variables into a lower-dimensional space. Just run either and take the first N components. The PLS vectors are more likely to be correlated with your target than the PCA ones.
- Ignoring the problem of correlation entirely, and using a model that is resilient to correlated variables, like Ridge Regression or any of the tree ensembles (RF, XGBoost, Bagged Trees, etc)

It might even be worth asking this question on the [Data Science](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange if you're looking for advice on how to approach this problem from a data science viewpoint instead of a coding one